# Not able to center Input elements in Div

Tags: html, css

I have tried googling but with no help most of them give solution as **margin:auto**
and also there are several questions on stackoverflow with same problem most of them have answer as margin:auto i am applying the same solution is not working for me

**HTML**

```
<div id="content" class="lcard">
    <center>
    <h1 class="n">Sign in To your<br> Crawler Account</h1><br>

<form onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

    <center><input name="Email" required type="email" placeholder="Email">

    <input name="Password" required type="Password" placeholder="Password" >

    <button type="submit"  class="b"><b>Sign In</b></button>
</center>

    <p id="reg" ><a href="C:/lcrawl/register.html" >New User Please Register</a></p>
</form>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.lcard
{
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    margin:left;

}
.n
{
    margin-bottom:50;
    left:-50%;
}
input
{
    padding: 5 10px;
    width:274px;
    height:44px;

    margin:auto;

}

.b
{
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color:#3079ed;
    width:274px;
    height:44px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: What parts are you trying to center?

Comment: What are you trying to center, it appears everything is centered in your code: http://jsfiddle.net/G4jt3/

Comment: all the input elements and position the div to left

Comment: Remove `center` element, but everything is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/M7pWC/

Comment: @chiwangc i am using eclipse its still the name and input elements to left

Comment: i think you want to use text-align:center for the div.

Comment: @Nik6019: If you want the placeholder text of the input elements to be centered, add `text-align: center;` to the `input` element. http://jsfiddle.net/G4jt3/1/

Comment: @nsthethunderbolt  yup working now with text-align:center for the div.  but in jsfiddle its doing without text-align:center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove OLD OLD `center` blocks, than just apply `text-align: center` to form and to header. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Justinas_Jurciukonis/M7pWC/1/)

```
.n
{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: but in jsfiddle its doing fine w/o text-align: center;

Answer (score 3):

Why you are giving margin left here??

```
.lcard
{
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    margin:left;

}
```

Comment: want the div element to be left in the page

Comment: then which element you want to center??

Comment: the entire form elements

Comment: div to the left and elements to the center, so there is only way,increase ur padding-left from Input

Comment: @ Chris Spittles Agreed chris.. But margin attribute wont take a value left so removing it and giving margin:auto will work if it is given for form element.. Thats why i mentioned this as an answer but my apologies if i had done something wrong

Answer (score 3):

First thing I noticed is the **margin: left** which I'm not sure about if it's a real value or not.

You should also check the attributes within your input elements. Types and other values seem strange, try to mess around with them first and then try using **input[type="text"]** and **input[type="submit"] in the CSS values, instead of just **input**.

Comment: changed to margin:auto auto auto 0;

Answer (score 3):

**Put your center tag before the first div as you call the id content**

```
    <div id="content" class="lcard">
    <center>
    <h1 class="n">Sign in To your<br> Crawler Account</h1><br>

    <form onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

    <center><input name="Email" required type="email" placeholder="Email">

    <input name="Password" required type="Password" placeholder="Password" >

    <button type="submit"  class="b"><b>Sign In</b></button>
    </center>

    <p id="reg" ><a href="C:/lcrawl/register.html" >New User Please Register</a></p>
    </form>
    </div>
```

**should be...**

```
    <center>
    <div id="content" class="lcard">

    <h1 class="n">Sign in To your<br> Crawler Account</h1><br>

    <form onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

    <center><input name="Email" required type="email" placeholder="Email">

    <input name="Password" required type="Password" placeholder="Password" >

    <button type="submit"  class="b"><b>Sign In</b></button>


    <p id="reg" ><a href="C:/lcrawl/register.html" >New User Please Register</a></p>
    </form>
    </div>
    </center>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed ur css a little

```
 .lcard
{
    background-color:#EEEEEE;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}
```

Now It's work in my PC.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's wrong with your code

```
Here is jsfiddle, with your code plus minor modification
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lb6mm/2/

[image: image description here]

Comment: What have you changed and why to leave deprecated elements?

Comment: thats what i am wondering its foing fine in jsfiddle but in chrome its shifting to left

Comment: usage of deprecated elements is fine. as long as accompanied with CSS `center{text-align:center;}` just as shorthand. I did it in my jsfiddle